# Laravel Database Table Update

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have added the table headers in the Laravel database.
I want to update and save.
The commands below cause my data to be deleted.

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
php artisan migrate:refresh
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

How do I update without deleting my data?

Comment: You can run `php artisan migrate` (without `:refresh`), this only runs migrations that have not been run yet.

The idea with migrations is that you do not edit them after you run them.
More info on migrations can be found in the [migration documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations)

Comment: sorry i don't fully understand. Isn't there a command I can do that?

Comment: It does not have to do with Laravel CLI. You have had used a wrong command. php artisan migrate:fresh will reset the schema and will delete data. If you have lost your data, I'm sorry but there is no command to return them for you on the application level. try to restore data on your database ends if they are critical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rollback only last migration

```
php artisan migrate:rollback --step=1
```

It should start function `down` on last migration